# Joint probability mass function of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, independence

I have a problem with two random variables $X$ and $T$ and a biased die with the probability of each outcome being $(p_i:i=1,...,6)$. So $T$ is the random variable where the die does $\textit{not}$ show a 6 and $X$ is the number shown on roll T. 
 So $T$~$Geo(1-p_6)$. I am told to find the joint distribution of $X$ and $T$. 
 I think $X$ and $T$ are independent and so the joint distribution would just be the product of the marginals. I know the pdf of $X$ but what would it be for $T$. I thought it would be $p_t(t) = p_6 \cdot \frac{p_i}{1-p_i} + p_i$ $for$ $i=1,...,5$ because I would have to add a percentage of $p_6$ to $(p_i:i=1,...,5)$ because $p_6$ does not occur when $X$ occurs. However I think this is incorrect because my answer is not the same as the
one on  the answer sheet.  
 The answer is $\mathbb{P}(X=x,T=t)=p_6^{t-1}p_x$ $for$ $x=1,...,5$

Comment: Can you check your question for typos? Especially the definitions of $X$ and $T$. You say $X$ is geometric yet $X$ is the result of the $T$th roll. Did you mean $T$ is the number of rolls until the die is not $6$, and $T \sim \text{Geometric}(1-p_6)$?

Comment: why should $X$ and $T$ be independent

Comment: "$T$ is the random variable where the die does not show a $6$" is unclear.

Comment: As implied by some previous comments, the wording of the question is ambiguous and (to the extent we can make any sense of it) seems self-contradictory. In addition to checking what you wrote to make sure it is what you meant, it might help to edit the question so as to add a word-for-word copy of the original question (carefully checked to be without errors in the copying) and the solution on the answer sheet. As the question stands right now, it is asking us to make too many guesses about what the real question is, which is not fair to anyone.

Comment: Sorry I have edited it now. @whoisit would $X$ and $T$ be independent because we knowing T occurs gives us no extra information about X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me clarify the details here:

Experiment: Suppose we roll a biased die repeatedly and independently till we observe a number that is not equal to 6.

Define $T$ as number of times the die is rolled in the process, and $X$ as the number obtained in the $T$th trial.

For example:- When the outcome is 665, then $T$ takes value 3, and $X$ takes value 5.

Joint PMF of $X$ and $T$ is

$p_{X, T}(x, t) = \Pr(X = x, T = t) = \Pr(T=t)\Pr(X=x|T=t)=\left(p_6^{t-1}(1-p_6)\right)\left(\dfrac{p_x}{1-p_6}\right) = p_6^{t-1}p_x $

where $x\in\{1,2,\ldots, 5\}$ and $t\in\mathbb{N}$.

Also,

$\displaystyle\Pr(X=x) = \sum_{t=1}^\infty\Pr(X = x, T = t)=\sum_{t=1}^\infty p_6^{t-1}p_x = \left(\dfrac{p_x}{1-p_6}\right) =\Pr(X=x|T=t)$

Therefore, $X$ and $T$ are independent.